# Napoleon Beis Din

Tags: history

Can somone provide some background for this like who was on it and what the Beis Din addressed and what was Napoleons motivation for it and what was the Jewish response?

Comment: I can't vouch for its accuracy, but you may want to see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Sanhedrin.

Comment: Closing as off topic (Jewish History), although NARQ would have been reasonable as well.

Comment: Sorry if this is a really stupid question, but was this a real sanhedrin -- and, if so, would it have been an opportunity to reinstate semicha? (I'm guessing the answers are "no" and "no," right?)